# Error:-too many values to unpack (expected 2), while trying to iterate over two columns in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, data-science

```
for L,M in laundry1['latitude'],laundry1['longitude']:
    print('latitude:-')
    print(L)
    print('longitude:-')
    print(M)
```

i am trying to iterate over the two columns of a data-frame, assigning there value to L & M and printing there value but it shows error of "too many values to unpack (expected 2) " view of the dataset with error view ->[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THpe6.png)

sample output:

latitude:-

22.1449787

18.922290399999998

22.1544736

22.136872

22.173595499999998

longitude:-

-101.0056829

-99.234332

-100.98580909999998

-100.9345736

-100.9946027

Comment: This: `laundry1['latitude'],laundry1['longitude']` creates a `tuple` object with exactly two elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for L,M in zip(laundry1['latitude'],laundry1['longitude']):
    print('latitude:-')
    print(L)
    print('longitude:-')
    print(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has his own iterate methods, if you just want to iterate over a dataframe values, without modifying it, i suggest you to use the [itertuples method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
import pandas as pd

values = [[22.1449787,-101.0056829]
         ,[18.922290399999998,-99.234332]
         ,[22.1544736,-100.98580909999998]
         ,[22.136872,-100.9345736]
         ,[22.173595499999998,-100.9946027]]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['latitude','longitude'])

for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.latitude)
    print(row.longitude)
```